Timing not authorized for defining the MAPt
Does anyone know why some charts have written "Timing not authorized for defining the MAPt"?
Could this happen when the DME required is written on the chart?
Thank you,

Can you post an example approach procedure with this notation?  Thanks -- and welcome to Av. SE!

“DME required” typically means that DME is required somewhere from the IAF through the missed approach. It does not mean that DME must be used to define the MAP. Some nations, following PANS OPS, will always show a rate of descent table that includes distances/timing from the FAF to threshold. The timing note indicates that the table cannot be used for defining the MAP.

I can share two examples: EFOU VOR RWY 12 (https://www.ais.fi/eaip/002-2024_2024_04_18/documents/Root_WePub/ANSFI/Charts/AD/EFOU/EF_AD_2_EFOU_12_VOR.pdf) and EFOU RWY 30 (https://www.ais.fi/eaip/002-2024_2024_04_18/documents/Root_WePub/ANSFI/Charts/AD/EFOU/EF_AD_2_EFOU_30_VOR.pdf)

From the designer's point of view, using PANS-OPS criteria will be necessary to do a study using Appendix to Chapter 6 - Refined Method for calculating MAPt and transitional tolerances for a Missed Approach point defined by a distance from the FAF?
Thank you,

There are two cases for this mention to be added:

The MAPt is collocated with a facility or a fix, there is no reason to use a timing from the FAF to identify the MAPt. This case is the one justifying the mention in the two | examples you have linked.

The MAPt is identified by a facility, but is not collocated with this facility. The timing may be useful to fly the final approach, however there can be an obstacle in the missed approach segment or some other reason (e.g. the proximity of a restricted area or a noise abatement procedure) which requires the missed approach to be executed accurately. In this case, if identifying the MAPt by timing is deemed not safe enough, the mention will be added (example below for Tokyo Intl).


From ICAO PAN-OPS vol 1 (Doc 8168):

8.4.4.2 If the missed approach point (MAPt) is defined by a facility or fix at the MAPt, the procedure will be annotated “Timing not authorized for defining the MAPt”.


6.1.5 When the MAPt is defined by a navigation facility or a fix, the distance from the FAF to the MAPt is normally published as well, and may be used for timing to the MAPt. In all cases where timing may not be used, the procedure is
annotated “timing not authorized for defining the MAPt”.

Example with such mention, LOC W RWY34R at Tokyo Intl. The MAPt is defined by the distance 0.7 NM to the ILS DME (ITC):


Okay, if timing from the FAF to the MAP isn't published, you can't use timing -- that's fair.  But, what sorts of characteristics of an approach cause the designers to decide that timing isn't an appropriate way to identify the MAP (in turn leading them to not put the timing info on the published product)?

@RalphJ: Because there is an obstacle in the missed approach segment, it is not safe to use timing for defining MAPt.

Could you share this approach with us? What is the airport?

@SarahFoxes: I added a link to this plate.

Per TERPS 2-9-8(c), this can happen when there is excessive fix error on the PFAF (precise final approach fix) and there are obstacles on the missed approach segment. The fix error on the PFAF is not allowed to exceed 1 nautical mile if timing from the FAF is used to identify the MAP, unless an additional buffer area is provided before the missed approach surface begins to account for the excessive error.

Is this based on timing inherently having greater error than DME (believable) or RNAV (believable) or NDB station passage (maybe) or other methods?  How is it determined that a given fix has however much error to it?

@RalphJ When the PFAF is identified from some ground station, the type of station, the distance to the station, and the bearing to the station all affect the fix error. DMEs has some ± distance or % of distance associated with them and VORs have some ± angle associated with them. TERPS has a bunch of pictures showing this. The issue is not just that timing has some inherent error but that if you are timing from the FAF which itself has a large error, then you have to add these errors together. If there is a way to identify the MAP independently then the error on the PFAF doesn't matter.
